# Is tagging is benifit in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, seo

I have wordpress website and around 200 plus links are index in google and half the link are taged url like:

http://domain.com/tag/text

Please suggest these tags are usefull or not for SEO purpose. If not then how can prevent to index these tag url in google.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just put a rel="nofollow" for each tag-link if you don't want Google to follow them. Also, use you robots.txt file to disallow the tag folder. Then they will not be indexed.

Bu tI don't see why you don't want them to be indexed. The only bad thing about tags is that the internal link juice will be weak if you have too many tags.